# Compiling FreeBSD on OSX

Tags: kernel, osx, compiling, freebsd

I currently have the source for the FreeBSD kernel. I want to compile it and create an iso image, on my OSX 10.9 computer. Can this be done? Do I need any other tools?

Comment: Less complicated than cross-compiling would be to spin up a freebsd virt, e.g. via VirtualBox or something.

Comment: This would have been a nice question for the freebsd [forums](https://forums.freebsd.org/), like this [post](https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/building-the-freebsd-kernel-on-another-os.32275/)

Answer (score 0):

A bootable ISO requires more than just a kernel, and cross-compiling is at the best of times a somewhat tricky business that requires installation of a complete cross-compiling tool chain.

FreeBSD, as far as I can see, does not provide official Live CDs as such, but they do offer [virtual machine images for a number of architectures](https://www.freebsd.org/where.html), and their ordinary installation image contains a ["Live CD" installation option](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/using-live-cd.html) for trying out the operating system (without a graphical user interface though).